# Implement IO operation Threadsafe using Rx

Tags: c#, synchronization, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am trying to implement a threadsafe File IO class. I understand that this can be achieved by locks and semaphore. But I want to use Rx as I am learning to use Rx. Can anyone help me to implement following contract of an IO operation using Rx in a threadsafe manner. I have couple of thoughts like creating like creating pipeline of external requests for saving or reading file, Scheduling all requests in orderly fashion. But I am struggling in how to implement. Please guide.

```
 public interface IFileIO
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Task which writes text to the file asynchronously
        /// </summary>
        Task WriteTextAsync(IsolatedStorageFileStream storageFile, string text);

        /// <summary>
        /// Task which reads text from the file asynchronously
        /// </summary>
        Task<string> ReadTextAsync(IsolatedStorageFileStream storageFile);
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate if I am trying to do something wrong. My objective here is learn if I can avoid using locks in scenarios like these. Which can help me to avoid many problems of locking mechanism like deadlocks..

Comment: It's fine to use Rx instead of TPL, just be mindful that Rx has the semantics of "zero or more" values, whereas TPL is "one and only one value". So anything that returns one value can certainly be modeled by something that returns zero or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I've missed something important, but your interface would look like this:

```
public interface IFileIO
{
    IObservable<Unit> WriteTextAsync(IsolatedStorageFileStream storageFile, string text);
    IObservable<string> ReadTextAsync(IsolatedStorageFileStream storageFile);
}
```

You would then implement this using an `System.Reactive.Concurrency.EventLoopScheduler` to perform all of the scheduling within the implementation. This will ensure that all of the operations are performed on a single thread. Makes super simple really.

The `Unit` type in the interface is `System.Reactive.Unit` and is used as a type to indicate `void` (or `Task` without a generic type). You should always use `System.Reactive.Unit.Default` to get the same instance of `Unit`.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity for the answer. I got the point that Task semantics of "one and only one value" and Rx is "zero or more" model. But is there a way in Task to avoid using locks, semaphore and implement IO library thread safe. Plus can i make this resource basic such that if multiple thread are trying to update single file then only it should pipeline there request else it can do in parallel if the file is different.

Comment: @BalrajSingh - The use of `EventLoopScheduler` will ensure thread safety as it will only let one observable run at a time. No locks or semaphores needed. It's a bit trickier to have individual file pipelines as I could name files like `"C:\Foo\..\Bar.txt"` or `"C:\Bar.txt"` and I'd be pointing at the same file. You're probably better off creating a "Unit of Work" object exclusively for each file, but that only works if you have coordinated file access.